# How can I create two one-to-many relationships between two tables with the same Primary Key in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, foreign-keys, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I have two tables; one called 'Application' the other called 'Connection'. The Application has a column [ID] and Connection as two columns [Application_ID1] and [Application_ID2]. The 'Application' table has other columns called [Status], [Theme], [Type], [Class], [Stage], and [Phase].

Therefore:
Application.ID = Connection.Application_ID1
AND
Application.ID = Connection.Application_ID2.

I would like to create some visuals that allows the user to filter between the other columns ([Status], [Theme], etc...) and return a table visual that shows all "Connections" (connections that contain [Application_ID1] and/or [Application_ID2]) that fall under those what was filtered.

Example: If I filter [Theme] to "Foundation", the Application table will return 5 applications (SQL, Power BI, PowerApps, PowerPoint, Excel), the table visual of the 'Connections' table should return the following:

| Application_1 | Application_2 |
| --- | --- |
| SQL | MS Teams |
| MS Word | Excel |
| Power BI | PowerApps |

The only problem is Power BI does not allow two relationships between two tables.

1.) I tried duplicating the Connection table and putting a UNION on them, making various measures to at times count one of the Connection tables vs. both. I run into an issue when I filter an Application and want to show when that application is [Application_ID1] and [Application_ID2].

2.) I tried duplicating the Application table, but was unsure how I can create a measure when filtering by Application to include both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those relationships will have to be Inactive. Only one Active relationship is allowed between two tables, but you can have multiple Inactive ones.

Then for measures, you can use [`USERELATIONSHIP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/userelationship-function-dax) function to "activate" an Inactive measure. For example:

```
Count Conn 1 = COUNTROWS('Connection')

Count Conn 2 = CALCULATE(
  COUNTROWS('Connection'),
  USERELATIONSHIP('Application'[ID], 'Connection'[Application_ID2])
)
```

You may find this a useful read: [Active vs inactive relationship guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/relationships-active-inactive)

For example, if you wanted to show rows in `Connection` based on the selection/filtering on `Application`, you could create a measure like this one.

```
Connection Count = 
  var x1 = COUNTROWS('Connection')
  var x2 = 
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('Connection'),
      USERELATIONSHIP('Application'[ID], 'Connection'[Application_ID2])
    )
  return x1 + x2
```

Then add this measure to your `Connection` table visual.

Comment: This is very helpful for counts, thank you! But if I wanted to display the, in a table, what applications are connected based on say status as a filter, do you know if I can still use that USERELATIONSHIP function?

Comment: Potentially, could you update your question above with what you are after. Provide a mock-up of the visual so we can see what your desired result would be. Also let us know of any other columns necessary, like where is the `status` column etc...

Comment: I have updated the question. Let me know if it is still unclear and thanks again for the help!

Comment: It does help, thank you. What other columns does `Connection` have that you want to show? For example if App1 is selected, it will show App1 in 'ID1' or 'ID2", and what else? If you have a sample/mock-up PBIX that you could share then that would help heaps.

Comment: I've updated the answer above with the `Connection Count` measure that you may want to try.

Comment: Thanks again for the response! So that measure seems to only return a COUNT, when I need to show the actual list of apps on both App1 and App2 (like shown in the example table above). Other columns in the 'Connection' table include [Category], [Status], [Frequency], and [Uncertainty].

Comment: Never mind I figured it out and it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Super, please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all.